# "TypeError: can't escape str to binary" when using form_choices in flask admin

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I have a flask admin table with a `String` column called `timezone`.

```py
class Warehouse(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'warehouses'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    display_name = db.Column(db.String)
    timezone = db.Column(db.String)
```

I have a `ModelView` for it that displays choices for `timezone` field in the modal:

```py
def timezones():
    return [(timezone, timezone) for timezone in pytz.all_timezones_set]


class WarehouseView(ModelView):
    form_choices = {
        "timezone": timezones()
    }
```

When creating or editing the modal, I can see the choices showing in the dropdown but when I save, I get the following error:

```
  File /venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 608, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
TypeError: can't escape str to binary
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong here?